# What are some efficient ways to compress a strictly ascending sequence of integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computer-science

Or let's say just a finite subset if bit width is a concern.

If the sequence ascends by a constant interval, then it's enough to specify the starting and ending numbers, and the interval.

But what about when the interval is a little less predictable, like the Fibonacci numbers of the prime numbers?

Comment: is this a computer sci question or a math question. For Fibonacci, it is enough to specify how the sequence starts, 1,1, and the recurrence relation, does that counts as compressing?

Comment: If the sequence is strictly ascending, then, obviously, the first step would be to use the sequence of differences, i.e., $a_0$, $a_1 - a_0 - 1$, $a_2 - a_1 - 1$, etc. Then you can use any other compression algorithm you like.

Comment: There are competing goals: Do you want the representation to take as little space as possible? Do you want to support fast enumeration, or fast lookups, or fast membership tests? And the Fibonacci numbers are so different from the prime numbers... What I'm saying is that the scope of this question is really wide, and you might want to narrow it down a bit. Is there a particular sequence and a particular application that you're especially interested in?

Comment: The most efficient compression is the shortest program that outputs the sequence. This is a very short program for the Fibonacci numbers and the primes but for other sequences could be very long. The keyword here is "Kolmogorov complexity."